# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.omg.stub.java.rmi._Remote_Stub cannot be cast to <Remote Business interface name>

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ejb-3.0

I am using WAS server and I have written a java client to call one EJB through business interface as follows:

```
Hashtable<String, String> envJNDIProperties = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                        envJNDIProperties.put("javax.naming.factory.initial", "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
                        envJNDIProperties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "iiop://indmtx981:24121");
                        envJNDIProperties.put("java.naming.security.principal", myTicket);
                        envJNDIProperties.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "NA");
                        envJNDIProperties.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass", "com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB");

                        InitialContext initialCtx = new InitialContext(envJNDIProperties);

                        Object ejbObject = null;

/*
* Giving me error in following line
*/                         
SearchServicesRemoteBusiness remoteBusiness = (SearchServicesRemoteBusiness) initialCtx.lookup("amdocs-RM-Billing/CM-L1/SearchServicesBean!amdocs.csm3g.sessions.views.business.remote.SearchServicesRemoteBusiness");

                        System.out.println("Got referencve for: "+ ejbObject.getClass().getName());
//                      SearchServicesRemoteBusiness remoteBusiness = (SearchServicesRemoteBusiness) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ejbObject,amdocs.csm3g.sessions.views.business.remote.SearchServicesRemoteBusiness.class);

                        AccountIdInfo accountId = new AccountIdInfo();

                        remoteBusiness.searchAccountById(accountId);
```

### Error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.omg.stub.java.rmi._Remote_Stub cannot be cast to .SearchServicesRemoteBusiness
        at EJBStandaloneClient.main(EJBStandaloneClient.java:27)

what i have tried: I use createEJBStubs.sh to create stub for this remote business interface and while running put this stub in client classpath, but error still exists.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in my class path, i was giving the full class location of stub, rather i should not include package structure in the class path. For e.g i have created stub in directory x/y/z//stub.class . So we should use x/y/z in class path not x/y/z//stub.class .

i corrected this and it is working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a call to [PortableRemoteObject.narrow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/rmi/PortableRemoteObject.html#narrow%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class%29):

```
SearchServicesRemoteBusiness remoteBusiness = (SearchServicesRemoteBusiness)
    PortableRemoteObject.narrow(initialCtx.lookup("amdocs-RM-Billing/CM-L1/SearchServicesBean!amdocs.csm3g.sessions.views.business.remote.SearchServicesRemoteBusiness"),
    SearchServicesRemoteBusiness.class);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was offline.
And, If I do so, then it is failing at following line: 
remoteBusiness.searchAccountById(accountId); with java.lang.NullPointerException 
i.e. in this case remoteBusiness is coming null.

Comment: That sounds like a product issue since PortableRemoteObject.narrow should not return null.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.